# вытащить данные из двух таблиц одним запросом. MySql

Tags: mysql, select

Есть две таблицы - `defCategories` и `userCategories`. Между ними нет связей, они отличаются. В `defCategories` два столбца - `id` и `defCategory`. В `userCategories` три столбца - `id` , `user_id` и `userCategory`. Как вытянуть все категории из `defCategories` и категории только к конкретному юзеру по `user_id` из `userCategories`?

1 - defCategories

```
id |  defCategories  |
1  |      Sport      |
2  |   Programming   |
3  |     Animals     |
```

2 - userCategories

```
id | user_id |  userCategory
1  |    1    |  Work
2  |    7    |  Home
3  |    3    |  Other
4  |    20   |  Food
```

На выходе хотелось бы получить все записи из `defCategories` и записи конкретного пользователя из `userCategories` одним запросом.

3 - Result (ожидаемый результат)

```
| defCategories |  userCategory
|     Sport     |  Work
|  Programming  |  Home
|    Animals    |  Other
|               |  Food
```

Примерно в таком виде.

Comment: Не понял вопрос

Comment: Всегда приводите в подобных вопросах образцы данных во входных таблицах и какие данные ожидаете на выходе. Ибо ничего не понятно. Если у таблиц ничего общего, то как вы предполагаете эти несвязанные данные расположить на выходе. Может вам нужен просто union, а может join ...

Comment: @Mike в шапку добавил примеры. Пробовал Union он мне всё в одно выдаёт, не по отдельности - тобишь получается такое: Sport Programming Animals Work Home Other Food С JOIN тоже не выходит. Получается так (Всё в одну строку получилось. там где `| |` это новая строка.)
`| Sport | Work  | 
| Sport | Home |
| Sport | Other | 
| Sport | Food  | 
| Programming | Work | 
| Programming | Home |
| Programming | Other | 
| Programming | Food |`
e.t.c...

Comment: А что вы хотели бы видеть на выходе. union похоже единственное что можно было бы применить. Только надо уточнить что такое "выдать по отдельности"

Comment: @Mike Добавил в шапку. Мне нужно потом понять где к чему относится а UNION всё в один столбец собирает и не понятно что откуда.

Comment: А зачем вам одним запросом получать абсолютно не относящиеся друг к другу данные. скорости это не прибавит. работать в одном цикле с данными разных видов не удобно. Можно конечно сделать `select NULL as defCategories, userCategory from userCategories union select defCategories, NULL from defCategories` правда записи будут строго отдельными строками, в одной строке Sport     |  Work не будет. А что бы вот прямо как вы хотели ... можно конечно сделать но оно того, поверьте, не стоит, запросик жутковатый будет

Comment: @Mike тобишь лучше двумя запросами?

Comment: @Tsyklop конечно

Comment: @Mike тут вот пришла мысль. а можно ли реализовать вытягивание этих данных в самоё MySql (функцией или процедурой)?

Comment: Реализовать можно почти все. вопрос а куда собственно эти данные вытягивать и с какой целью

Answer (score 1):

1) select  defCategory from defCategories

2) select  userCategory from userCategories where user_id = <что Вы хотите>

Comment: хотелось бы один запросом.

Comment: **хотелось бы один запросом** Вы очень туманно излагает то, что хотите получить. Но тут, как я понимаю, должен действовать принцип всех честных торговцев: "Клиент должен получить то, что ему НУЖНО, а не то, что он ХОЧЕТ.  Так вот, с моей точки зрения, Вам НУЖНО :  **select userCategor, defCategory from userCategories, defCategories where user_id = defCategories.id**  Это мне так интуиция подсказывает... Хотя могу и быть не прав...

Comment: добавил в шапку то что нужно.

Comment: **автор вопроса фактически именно это и делает** вариант SQL запроса, который я Вам предложил, сформирует именно такой ответ, за исключением последней строки:

Comment: Это строка в Вашем примере, которая содержит:   **Food**

Comment: Подозреваю, что Вы просто не совсем корректно сформировали таблицу userCategories. Последняя строка в ней должна быть такой: (4, 3, "Fuud"). Тогда Вы получите именно то, что Вам нужно...

Comment: В этом вся и загвоздка. что эти таблицы не связаны между собой и не должны быть по задумке. Спасибо за ваши предложения. Придётся делать два запроса.